# Drop e-mail from mail.app into NSWindow object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, email

I have an cocoa app where I would like to accept e-mails from mail.app dragged into the main window of the app. I have in my applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
[_window registerForDraggedTypes:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       NSFilenamesPboardType,
      (NSString *)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise, nil]]; //kUTTypeData
[_window setDelegate:(id) self];
```

This works fine, I can receive a document, in my performDragOperation: using

```
NSArray * files =  [sender namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:url];
```

However, this only lets me drag the emails one-by-one. If I mark several emails, everything seems OK until I drop, then nothing happens. The performDragOperation is not even called.

I have tried to add kUTTypeData to the registerForDraggedTypes..., and then I get the performDragOperation... called, but then I cannot use the namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:url as it returns a nil pointer.

When I had the kUTTypeData included in the register... I included this in the performDragOperation to see what types in drag:

```
pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
NSLog(@"perform drag entered, %@", [pboard types]);
```

With the following result:

```
2013-07-25 15:09:50.771 BO2ICAL[1672:303] perform drag entered, (
"dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y4zvanr41a3pwfz30n25wqz4ca5pfsr30c35feb4he2pssrxgn6vasbu1g7dfqm10c6xeeb4hw6df",
"MV Super-secret message transfer pasteboard type",
"dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8zg7puqz3c465fqr3gn7bakf41k55rqf4g86vasbu1g7dfqm10c6xeeb4hw6df",
"Super-secret Automator pasteboard type"
)
```

While the list for single e-mails are:

> 2013-07-25 15:14:30.096 BO2ICAL[1672:303] perform drag entered, (
>       "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y4zvanr41a3pwfz30n25wqz4ca5pfsr30c35feb4he2pssrxgn6vasbu1g7dfqm10c6xeeb4hw6df",
>       "MV Super-secret message transfer pasteboard type",
>       "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8zg7puqz3c465fqr3gn7bakf41k55rqf4g86vasbu1g7dfqm10c6xeeb4hw6df",
>       "Super-secret Automator pasteboard type",
>       "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwa3xmrvw1gkdusm1044pxqyuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu",
>       "Apple files promise pasteboard type",
>       "public.url",
>       "CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x75726C20",
>       "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwaznwmuuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu",
>       "Apple URL pasteboard type",
>       "public.url-name",
>       "CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x75726C6E",
>       "com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-content-type",
>       "com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-url",
>       "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y6y4usm1044pxqzb085xyqz1hk64uqm10c6xenv61a3k",
>       NSPromiseContentsPboardType
>       )

Does anyone have any advice how to do this correctly in order to accept multiple e-mails?

Comment: I'd submit it to Apple's Bug Reporter.  Dragging a single Mail.app message to a Finder window produces a .eml file, and dragging to a plain text editor produces the message's subject, and dragging to a rich text editor produces the message's subject as a hyperlink to the message.  Dragging multiple Mail.app messages is useless outside of Mail, though; it appears good only for moving messages between mailboxes.  As a workaround, you could ask users to copy messages and paste them into your app.

Comment: Thanks. The purpose is to put the mails into a database where it can be connected to company, project, etc. In my case i use mailcore2 to parse the eml files and put them into this database. If the user want to drag several mails this makes totally sense for this project.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this. I found that the data provided in the mode "kUTTypeData" gave me enough data to grab the files directly from the mail.app mailbox.

In the mbox folder, there is a folder with a long sequence of numbers and dashes, there was no trace of this name anywhere in the mailbox hierarchy, but since this only contains this folder and an info.plist file, I used this function to grab that name: Update: implemented regexp check since the folder sometimes contains sub-mailboxes that can have a longer name...

```
-(NSString*)FindCodedFolderInMailbox:(NSString*)mailboxpath {

     NSString *uuid_regexp = @"[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}";
     NSPredicate *uuid_test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", uuid_regexp];

     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     NSArray *fileList = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:mailboxpath error:nil];
     for (NSString * file in fileList) {
         if ([uuid_test evaluateWithObject: file]){
             return file;
         }
     }
     return nil;
}
```

Then the section where I find there is no "NSPromiseContentsPboardType", but instead a "Super-secret Automator pasteboard type", I wrote the following section (There is some NSLog entries I intend to remove, but here it is:

```
} else if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:@"Super-secret Automator pasteboard type"] ) {

     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     // Create the URL for the destination folder and ensure it exists. 
     NSURL *applicationFilesDirectory = [self applicationFilesDirectory];
     NSURL *url = [applicationFilesDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"documents"];
     BOOL isDir;
     if (!([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[url path] isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir)) {
         NSError * error = nil;
         [ fileManager createDirectoryAtURL:url withIntermediateDirectories: YES attributes:nil error:&error];
         if (error) {
             [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
         }
     }
     BOOL ok = false;

  // locate the mailbox path....
    NSString *mailboxpath = [pboard stringForType:@"MV Super-secret message transfer pasteboard type"];
    NSLog(@"Mailboxpath: %@", mailboxpath);

    NSString * codedFolder = [self FindCodedFolderInMailbox:mailboxpath];
    if (codedFolder) {
        NSString * codedpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/%@/Data", mailboxpath, codedFolder];
        NSURL * mb1 = [NSURL URLWithString:codedpath];
        NSLog(@"Directory:%@", mb1);
        NSArray *msgArray = [pboard propertyListForType:@"Super-secret Automator pasteboard type"];
        if (msgArray) {
            for (NSDictionary *msg in msgArray) {

                // Locate the message....
                NSNumber * msgID = [msg valueForKey:@"id"];
                NSLog(@"Melding(%@):%@", msgID, msg);
                NSString * filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.emlx", msgID];

                // second and first letter of id
                NSString * idSec = [[msgID stringValue]substringWithRange:(NSRange){1, 1}];
                NSString * idFirst = [[msgID stringValue]substringWithRange:(NSRange){0, 1}];
                NSString * subpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/Messages/%@",idSec, idFirst,  filename];

                NSURL * thisFilePath = [mb1 URLByAppendingPathComponent:subpath];


                if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[thisFilePath path]]) {

                    NSURL *destpath = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

                    NSError * error = nil;
                    [fileManager copyItemAtURL:thisFilePath toURL:destpath error:&error];
                    if (error) {
                        [[NSApplication sharedApplication]presentError:error];
                    } else {
                        [self ParseEmlMessageforPath:[destpath path] filename:filename];

                    }


                }

            }


        }

    }
```

And here we go.... :-)